# Broken Wordpress site,after uploading a plugin manually

Tags: wordpress

I am really really dumb.Today i decided to upload a plugin which is a cool slider plugin in my wordpress site.I added it by wordpress add menu ([this one](http://prntscr.com/desk5v)).After uploadng it  clicked on install now.After the install it automatic refreshed/redirectet me to page in my website,which is when there is no content found(blank page wth footer on which is typed "No content found,maybe tr with a search").After i clicked on my Logo to get me on home page there was no home page,[this](http://prntscr.com/deslf2) is how it looks right now.
Only header i showing...No wordpress admin bar,no content.
So:

1.I have access to wordpress dashboard with /wp-admin?,but plugin which i "installed" isn't showing in plugin list..

2.I cannot find the plugin which i uploaded anywhere in my files folder.It's missing like nothing happened,but my page content is removed...
Please if any1 know fix,or guess where to find and delete the plugin,answer.Please !

Comment: okay follow my instructiom

Comment: Rename manually the new plugin folder to desactivate it

Comment: @Benoti  cannot find the plugin in folder

Comment: @Vasim, wp-content/plugins/XXXXX with ftp.

Comment: @Benoti Yes,Its possible but, In question say that **2. I cannot find the plugin which i uploaded anywhere in my files folder.**

Comment: Some people never think to refresh their filezilla folder. If it's really a plugin, it's necessary here or in mu-plugins folder ? Or it's a cracked premium plugin and then....

Comment: Its an exception case.But I think good point

Answer (score 0):

**Remove plugin from Database**

1) Go to cpanel

2) Go to PHPmyadmin (take Backup of database)

3) Select a running  plugin a

```
select * from wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

4) Copy value field some where.

5) Now,Run following query,

```
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

6) You have all post there.

7) activate plugins from admin panel one by one.

That's it.

**Note**
Plugin break any execution  this will work,In case post are deleted from DB,this will no work.for check,Please go to `wp_post` and check all things are there.

Comment: All things in wp_post are there,but i cannot find 'active_plugins' column,it is in wp_options,right:? This is what  i get http://prntscr.com/desvl8

Comment: No,Its inside 'wp_options' table

Comment: did you run above sql query.

Comment: @UmreteKurvi Excuse me for minute.

Comment: @UmreteKurvi please execute both seprately and remove semicolon

Comment: http://prntscr.com/det67m think its done,now i must enable 1 by 1 the plugins right :?


EDIT:Site is still the same http://prntscr.com/det6l2

Comment: please do one by one as i said

Comment: can you access a admin??

Comment: absolutelly nothing,i just refreshed my website.Yap i can access admin

Comment: admin accessible or not??

Comment: ok.Just go to appreance and change theme to default.update paramlinks fro settings

Comment: can we please move to chat box instead of commenting here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129684/discussion-between-vasim-vanzara-and-umrete-kurvi).

Comment: All think can be done mate here is URL: http://shreddingnation.com/ 
My Skype is: Dankata1231 if you wanna move to chat,i don't know is there is a chat in this website here.
And 1 more thing i must go do some work at the moment,will be here after 3 hours Iám really thankfull for your time and help,if you wanna add me on skype.

Comment: can't add you,its next to impossible :),I am at workplace.

Comment: can you add me as user in to access admin??It better to check admin

Comment: mail credetial  me at vasimmca007atgmail.com

Comment: to join me in chat room just click on this : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129684/discussion-between-vasim-vanzara-and-umrete-kurvi

Comment: @UmreteKurvi do you get a solution??

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by turning on Wordpress Debug mode!And the error wasn't from uploading a plugin,but from other plugin that i had.That's why it was so confusing.I removed the short code for this plugin and site is running as usual.